# AsyncStorage.getItem is returning undefined

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I'm setting a 'session' variable using AsyncStorage in my action file:

```
axios
...
// Session variable
AsyncStorage.setItem('userID', response.data.toString()).then((user) => {
    this.setState({ user });
});
// Send to next page
NavigationService.navigate('Main');
```

Then, in my page, I tried to get the value:

```
...
render() {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('userID')
      .then((value) => {
        const data = JSON.parse(value);
        console.log('userID ', data.name);
      });
...
```

It is returning 'userID undefined'. Why is it happening?

Thanks

Comment: What is the value of `response.data.toString()`?

Comment: It is a number. The value is 10 when I do a console.log(response.data.toString())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the code you've written is that `userId` has the value `10` but when you call `console.log` you're treating it like an object with an attribute `name`. The correct code would look like:

```
...
render() {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('userID')
      .then((value) => {
        const userId = JSON.parse(value);
        console.log('userID ', userId);   // This line changed
      });
...
```